# Docker: wordpress dev sandboxed environment

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, docker

I don't work with WP neither PHP. But sometimes I'm asked to have a look at a wordpress site (we've all been through this ... sight)

Instead of installing LAMP or whatever, I'd rather sandbox the shit in a docker, so I can easily uninstall everything once done.

I find the `docker-compose` approach as suggested in the [official wordpress](https://hub.docker.com/_/wordpress/) docker kind of complicated.

Instead, since it is for development purpose **only**, I'd rather have a single Docker that would contain the whole PHP + MySQL config, and simply having to:

1. Replace `DB_NAME`, `DB_USER`, `DB_PASSWORD` and `DB_HOST` in `wp-config.php`
2. Import the SQL of the existing DB. Eg. `docker run mydocker /bin/mysql-import ~/Desktop/export.sql`
3. `docker start mydocker --source ~/Workspace/myproject`

Does this approach make sense? Are there any ressource I could find to achieve this (if it hasn't been done already)?

Answer (score 0):

This shall certainly be improved, but here are the steps I took:

1. [Install Docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/installation/) if not already done
2. Install the [Lamp Docker](https://hub.docker.com/r/linode/lamp/) (I'd have rather used nginx instead of apache but anyways): `docker pull linode/lamp`
3. Run `sudo docker run -p 80:80 -v <local_path_to_site_sources>:/var/www/<sitename> -t -i linode/lamp /bin/bash`

At this step, you have forwarded Docker's port 80 to your host 80 (which means you can try out http://localhost and should get a result), entered into the docker's bash with `/var/www/<sitename>` containing your source code.

Unfortunately there is still some little config to make, which should be automated IMHO.

4. Run `apt-get update` (no more sudo, you are root there)
5. Run `apt-get install php5-mysql` (for some unfortunate reason, the package was missing)
6. Make sure the path `/var/www/<sitename>/log` exists by running `mkdir -p /var/www/<sitename>/log`
7. Run `nano /etc/apache2/sites-available/<sitename>.conf` with the following content (everything's detailed [there](https://www.linode.com/docs/websites/hosting-a-website)):

   ServerAdmin webmaster@ # Probably not mandatory
      ServerAlias  # Probably not mandatory

   # Index file and Document Root (where the public files are located)
      DirectoryIndex index.html index.php
      DocumentRoot /var/www/
      # Log file locations
      LogLevel warn
      ErrorLog  /var/www//log/error.log
      CustomLog /var/www//log/access.log combined
8. Run `a2ensite <sitename>`
9. The database needs to be created before being imported anyways (maybe there a way to avoid this): `mysql -u root -p` password: `Admin2015` as explained [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/linode/lamp/)
10. Run in-there `create database <dbname>;` then `exit`
11. Import current data if exists: `mysql -u root -p <dbname> < <dbbackupfile>.sql` (note that the `<dbbackupfile>.sql` needs to be available in the docker, so putting in into your `<local_path_to_site_sources>` shall help.
12. Update (from your host, not the docker, the files are shared) `wp-config.php` with:

    /** Nom de la base de données de WordPress. */
    define('DB_NAME', '');

    /** Utilisateur de la base de données MySQL. */
    define('DB_USER', 'root');

    /** Mot de passe de la base de données MySQL. */
    define('DB_PASSWORD', 'Admin2015');

    /** Adresse de l'hébergement MySQL. */
    define('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1');
13. Run `service apache2 restart; service mysql restart`
14. Go check http://localhost : annnnnndd DONE!!